# Computer temperatures on laptop

Tags: laptop, temperature

Does a laptop get hotter if I am playing a game and I am inside an area where there is lava? I feel like the fans get faster if I am playing in a lava area but if I play in an ice world, the computer gets cooler?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! That is surely a weird question. The fans of your computer only speed up if the CPU gets hotter. The game world itself doesn't directly have an effect on the temperature, only if the game area is more graphically challenging. Ice or lava shouldn't matter. Maybe you just feel that way?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen, what, you never saw The Matrix?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the lava requires more calculations to model than what it replaced. An iceberg could speed up the CPU and/or GPU and cause more calculations which causes more heat.

Answer (score 1):

Lava moves more than ice, so it might be harder to render, causing the CPU/GPU to do more work, causing it to get hotter.

So what you're experiencing might be right, but it has nothing to do with it being lava/ice.